# Giving a value(price) to an array(pizza) inside a select form

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, select

//we are trying to give each pizza of the array a price as a number value.
We need to keep the structure of the array inside the select form.
Then we need to print it in another php file, how to call the values?

```
     <fieldset>
            <p>ORDENE SU PIZZA</p>

<select name= "pizza">
    <option>Seleccione su Pizza</option>
    <?php
    $tiposdepizza = array ("Pizza Quattro Formaggi","Pizza Margherita","Pizza Marinara","Pizza Bianca",
    "Pizza Ortolana","Pizza 4 Stagioni","Pizza Diavola","Pizza Focosa","Pizza Pastorella",
    "Pizza Alla Casalinga","Pizza Personalizada");
    foreach($tiposdepizza as $pizza){
    ?>
    <option><?php echo $pizza; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>

             <p></p>
      </fieldset>

      <select name= "tamaño">
    <option>Seleccione el Tamaño</option>
    <?php
    $tamaños = array ("Alto","Grande","Venti");
    foreach($tamaños as $tamaño){
    ?>
    <option><?php echo $tamaño; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select> <br>
<p></p>

     <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Guardar">


    </form>
    </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

To give a value to your array you can do:

```
$tiposdepizza['Pizza Quattro Formaggi'] = "19";
$tiposdepizza['Pizza Margherita'] = "21";
$tiposdepizza['Pizza Diavola'] = "17";
```

**OR**

```
$tiposdepizza = array("Pizza Quattro Formaggi"=>"19", "Pizza 
Margherita""=>"21", "Pizza Diavola"=>"17");
```

So we have **two ways** for give a "value" to an array. For me my favorite is the first method but the two are same so it's up to you to see which one you prefer.

Questions? Ask them  ;)

For more informations, you can read: 
[http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php](http://PHP%20Arrays%20(Official%20docs))

Comment: Thank you so much, now we need to print the name of the pizza and the price value in other php file, is not replacing the name(pizza) for the new value(number)?

Comment: Include your php file. You can do: include "myfile.php"; and you will able to get the array and print it.